# Load an UIImage from Documents directory and cache it

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching

I have an `UIImage` in the Documents directory.
I would like to load it and cache it in the memory.

To create and cache a UIImage, we should use `+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name` method, but the problem with this methods is that the image should be in the application bundle. When i use the other methods, `initWithContentsOfFile`, ... the image is not cached.

How to load an `UIImage` from the documents directory and cache it ?

Comment: You need to create your own caching mechanism for images loaded with anything other than `imageNamed:`.

Comment: do you have an idea how to create a caching mechanism ?

Comment: NSDictionary will work. You just need a way to clear the cache when memory gets low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `NSCache` to your AppDelegate, and have a method like:

```
- (UIImage *)cachedImageWithFilePath:(NSString *)path {
    // first check for a hit in the cache
    UIImage *cachedImage = [_imageCache objectForKey:path];
    if (cachedImage)
      return cachedImage;

    // load the image from disk and add to the cache
    UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [_imageCache setObject:newImage forKey:path];
    return newImage;
}
```

Edit:

Article on [NSCache](http://nshipster.com/nscache/), [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @rmaddy "NSCache is basically just an NSMutableDictionary that automatically evicts objects in order to free up space in memory as needed. No need to respond to memory warnings or contrive a cache-clearing timer mechanism." - from the linked article

Comment: Sorry. I glossed over the `NSCache` part and thought you were using `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks four your answer. Accept your answer but i will not put the method in the AppDelegate :)